# I keep getting errors on my code SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

So I've been working on this code for a few days now and I can't figure out why I'm getting errors.  These are the errors I'm getting:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "PATIENTID_FK": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

and

```
SQL Error: ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
```

I've included the code that I wrote.  The "..." symbolizes not important information from the table I was creating, such as "DoctorFirstName".  Can someone help me figure out where I'm messing up?  Thank you!

```
DROP TABLE HealthRecord;
DROP TABLE Patient;    
DROP TABLE Insurance;
DROP TABLE Doctor;
DROP TABLE Hospital;
DROP TABLE Prescription;

CREATE TABLE Insurance (
InsuranceID number,
...
CONSTRAINT InsuranceID_pk
PRIMARY KEY (InsuranceID));

CREATE TABLE Prescription (
PrescriptionID number,
...
CONSTRAINT PrescriptionID_pk
PRIMARY KEY(PrescriptionID));

CREATE TABLE Hospital (
HospitalID number,
...
CONSTRAINT HospitalID_pk
PRIMARY KEY(HospitalID));

CREATE TABLE Doctor (
DoctorID number,
...
HospitalID number,
CONSTRAINT DoctorID_pk
PRIMARY KEY(DoctorID),
CONSTRAINT HospitalID_fk
FOREIGN KEY (HospitalID)
REFERENCES Hospital (HospitalID));

CREATE TABLE Patient (
PatientID number,
...
InsuranceID number,
CONSTRAINT PatientID_pk
PRIMARY KEY (PatientID),
CONSTRAINT InsuranceID_fk
FOREIGN KEY (InsuranceID)
REFERENCES Insurance(InsuranceID));

CREATE TABLE HealthRecord(
RecordID number,
...
DoctorID number,
PrescriptionID number,
PatientID number,
CONSTRAINT RecordID_pk
PRIMARY KEY(RecordID),
CONSTRAINT DoctorID_fk
FOREIGN KEY (DoctorID)
REFERENCES Doctor (DoctorID),
CONSTRAINT PrescriptionID_fk
FOREIGN KEY (PrescriptionID)
REFERENCES Prescription (PrescriptionID),
CONSTRAINT PatientID_fk
FOREIGN KEY (PatientID_fk)
REFERENCES Patient(PatientID));
```

Comment: Do all the `DROP` statements run without error? Try dropping them using `drop table ... cascade constraints`. Maybe you have other tables in your schema that use that FK name. After you have dropped all tables, run `select table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type from user_constraints` to check if there are still any constraints left in your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dropping the table doesn't remove the constraints. So you constraints still exist. You should drop the constraints and indexes. Check this link out:

https://www.1keydata.com/sql/alter-table-drop-constraint.html

Reference the link below for dropping tables and the constraint in one statement (CASCADE CONSTRAINTS)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9003.htm

Comment: Thank you!  I tried the ALTER TABLE Doctor DROP CONSTRAINT HospitalID_fk and I got this error:

SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: If you are still running into the error, you could try creating the tables again, then try dropping constraints

Comment: Dropping a table **will** drop all foreign keys. If the table _references_ other tables, those FKs will be dropped automatically. If the table is _referenced_ by others you can only drop the table using `drop table ... cascade constraints`

Comment: Okay.  So, I tried the cascade constraints and I STILL get the same error.  I really don't get it